# How to allow only backspace and movements in a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking for a jquery function that only allows a movements with arrow keys and backspace in a textarea, but the movements with the arrow keys don't work correctly.

```
 function moveArrow(e){
    if(e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40){     
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#installId').keypress(function (e) 
    { return deleteItem(e,false) });

  $('#installId').keydown(function (e) 
    { return deleteItem(e,false) }); 

  $('#installId').keypress(function (e) 
        { return moveArrow(e) });

  $('#installId').keydown(function (e) 
        { return moveArrow(e) }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to preventDefault on other key press

```
$('#installId').keypress(function (e){
        if(e.which < 37 || e.which > 40)
              e.preventDefault();
    });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/natchkebiailia/Vftjt/)

Comment: I guess `e.which` is not working properly in FF but `e.keyCode` does

Comment: it's not a cross browser working example, I hope the author of this question get the right idea how it's done.

Comment: But your example doesnt work for me cuz i use FF. That's what i'm trying to say and if i change the OP code to `e.keyCode` it does work